# Is there some tool or mode for refactoring ruby code in emacs?

Tags: ruby, emacs, refactoring

I am looking for some tool that supports me in refactoring ruby code.

I know that it is very hard to implement these kind of tools for a dynamic language like ruby, but I also know there are different solutions for [RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/features/ruby_ide.html#Intelligent_Code_Improvement) and [Vim](https://github.com/ecomba/vim-ruby-refactoring) to                              help with basic stuff like "extract method" and "rename method".

It does not seem very practical to have multiple editors / IDEs open, so I am searching something specifically for emacs.

Comment: [I dare](https://github.com/ecomba/vim-ruby-refactoring)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a project called [ruby-refactor](https://github.com/ajvargo/ruby-refactor) with recent activity. It can be installed through MELPA. It was inspired by a plugin for Vim called `vim-refactoring-ruby`. It seems to work well upon my first impression.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will be exactly what you looking for, but maybe you can take a look at
[Rdefs](https://github.com/knsmr/rdefs)

> Rdefs is a tiny Ruby script that extracts class, module, method,
>   attribute definitions from a given Ruby source code.
>
> **Use Rdefs with Emacs**
>
> You might want to put etc/rdefs.el into your elisp directory and add
>   something like this to your dot.emacs:
>
> (require 'rvm)
>
> (rvm-use-default)
>
> (require 'rdefs)

Hope it helps a bit... but anyway there seem to be no alternatives at the moment.

You could also try and check [Rsense](http://cx4a.org/software/rsense/) status:

> **RSense** is a Ruby development tools, which is specialized for high
>   function text editors such as Emacs, Vim, etc. Following UNIX
>   philosophy, RSense has a high transparency and is easy to learn,
>   extend and fix for users. Adopting copyleft license, it also keeps
>   being a free software.
>
> In the future, the following features will be available:
>
> ```
> Static code checking
> Caller jump
> Refactoring
> ```

But there has been no activity on the project [github](https://github.com/m2ym/rsense) page for 1 year now ([new branch for v 2.0](https://github.com/m2ym/rsense/tree/2.0))

Maybe you could try to get in contact with the author...